# What gift am I?

Tags: riddle, word

I am intangible
Once given, I can never be regained
I am always given as a pair
I can give a gift of my own
Everyone has me exactly once

I ask you: What am I

Comment: This is just too broad. I'm voting to close it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

> Virginity:
>  Not a real, physical thing.
>  You can't un-boink.
>  Can result in children.
>  You have it from birth until you lose it.

Edit:

> and of course, it takes two (or more) to tango ;)

Comment: Bingo! That is correct!

Comment: I feel like some of the other unintended answers fit better than this one.

Comment: I also agree there are better answers than this. Virginity isn't always given as a pair; virgins can have sex with non-virgins, they can also lose it to sex toys. Also, virginity itself doesn't give children; you can't ever have children until *long after* you lose your virginity.

Comment: While not always given as a pair, it takes at least a pair to give it.  I don't see how solo masturbation of any type counts as intercourse, toys or not.  While one could debate that point, other terms for it ("coupling" comes to mind) imply that it does indeed take two.  A loss of virginity (giving the gift) can absolutely cause children.  It doesn't have to, but sex is the leading cause of birth.  The fact that it takes a while doesn't change that.

Answer (score 12):

My guess is

> Life.
>  It cannot be regain after death.
>  Its intangible.
>  Given by two parents.
>  You can give another life.
>  And you live exactly once.

Comment: I'd say your answer is given *by* a pair, not *as* a pair.

Comment: @jamesdlin It is given as a pair of cells which later bond to form one thing.

Comment: @jamesdlin "Given as a pair" as in "given jointly". By analogy with something like "We gave a gift as a family."

Comment: Pedantically, plants, bacteria and even some simple animals can give the gift singly. So maybe the answer should be something like "human ____". Super-pedantically, humans can give the gift in groups of three, [with appropriate technology](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/health-27682884), but I doubt the question was considering that case!

Comment: @DavidRicherby Not even only simple animals: Komodo dragons can do it singly!

Comment: Accurately you can regain life. For example resuscitation from a heart attack.

Comment: Your username reminds me of something...

Comment: as a pair of Body and Soul

Comment: As a pair of sperm and egg I will say

Answer (score 6):

My guess would be

> Love

**Explanation line by line:**

I am intangible

> Love is an emotion.

Once given, I can never be regained

> Its hard to let something go you love.

I am always given as a pair

> Love is always between two things.

I can give a gift of my own

> Love can give the ability to reproduce.

Everyone has me exactly once

> The love of your life.

Comment: This looks like the most likely answer so far ... +1

Comment: I disagree with the pair reasoning. It can be unrequited.

Comment: @Pharap for many people it seems impossible tho.

Answer (score 6):

My try: I am

> a name

I am intangible

> A name is intangible

Once given, I can never be regained

> Once you give a name to a baby you can't get it back, that doesn't makes sense.

I am always given as a pair

> You get a pair of firstname/lastname on birth

I can give a gift of my own

> You "gift" your lastname to your child

Everyone has me exactly once

> Everyone has only one name

Comment: Most people are given at least one middle name as well forming a triplet.

Comment: @Warlord099 Technically you can have more than just one, but people are usually just asked for first and last names, middle names aren't as important as they used to be.

Comment: @Warlord099 I though of middle names (I've been gifted with 3 of these ._.) but they are generally unused, so I ignored this aspect of a full name since it still stick pretty much to the riddle :)

Comment: @Pharap Which is why i said "at least one" I guess I should have also said "forming at least a triplet.

Comment: @Goombi I'm not sure where you live, but almost every major form I have to fill out and/or sign requires at least the middle initial.

Comment: **1 -** I disagree with "name". It is *not always* given as a pair. Where I come from, women receive their husband's last name upon marriage; a name which is *not* given as a pair. **2 -** It is *you* who give your name to your children, not your name itself. **3 -** Even if we ignore God who has many names, and self-given names (pen names, usernames, etc.), there's still me: I was given a western name by my Westerner father (first, last, and 1 middle name), and I was also given a Chinese name by my Chinese mother (a first name; the last is a transcript of my father's last name).

Comment: @Warlord099 Where I live in Britain it's almost never asked for.

Answer (score 1):

I would say,

> death

I am intangible

> Can you really touch death?

Once given, I can never be regained

> It can't be regain as it cant be lost

I am always given as a pair

> Clinical death and brain death

I can give a gift of my own

> If somebody dies can leave some inheritance to his family and that might be consider as gift (especially if person who died is some far relative who you even didn't know exist), or maybe it is red herring

Everyone has me exactly once

> You can die only once

I ask you: What am I

Comment: There is a death that doesn't come as pair.

Comment: @Izzy Which death are you thinking of? Brain death guarantees clinical death, clinical death used to guarantee brain death but "there is no specific duration of clinical death at which the non-functioning brain clearly dies", despite the fact the brain immediately stops functioning.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty similar to Izzy's answer, but my guess is:

> Birth

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Please could you add some explanation as to why this answer fits the question as stated? Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is:

> A brain.

I am intangible

> Your brain is inside your head, and therefore not tangible (by you, at least).

Once given, I can never be regained

> You can have a brain transplant, but you can never have your own brain again.

I am always given as a pair

> The brain is divided into two lobes - thus, a pair.

I can give a gift of my own

> Knowledge is the greatest gift of all.

Everyone has me exactly once

> Metaphysically, we only ever have one mind.